# Escaping dots in java. (StringEscapeUtil)

Tags: java, apache-commons

This is probably a super dumb question, but I can't work out why StringEscapeUtils is behaving in this manner.

It's the second assert that's failing, with the following error:

> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Did not escape correctly  Expected
>   :`t\.ext` Actual   :`t.ext`

Tests

```
public class ServerDataTest {
    @Test
    public void escape() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("Did not escape correctly", "text", ServerData.escape("text"));
        assertEquals("Did not escape correctly", "t\\.ext", ServerData.escape("t.ext"));
        assertEquals("Did not escape correctly", "te\\\\xt", ServerData.escape("te\\xt"));
        assertEquals("Did not escape correctly", "te\\\\\\.xt", ServerData.escape("te\\.xt"));
    }
}
```

Escaper utility

```
private final static Map<CharSequence, CharSequence> ESCAPE_MAP = new HashMap<>();{
        ESCAPE_MAP.put("\\", "\\\\");
        ESCAPE_MAP.put(".",  "\\.");
    }

    private static LookupTranslator ESCAPE = new LookupTranslator(ESCAPE_MAP);

    private final static Map<CharSequence, CharSequence> UNESCAPE_MAP = new HashMap<>();{
        UNESCAPE_MAP.put("\\\\", "\\");
        UNESCAPE_MAP.put("\\.", ".");
    }

    private static LookupTranslator UNESCAPE = new LookupTranslator(UNESCAPE_MAP);

    static String escape(String text){
        return StringEscapeUtils.builder(ESCAPE).escape(text).toString();
    }

    static String unescape(String text){
        return StringEscapeUtils.builder(UNESCAPE).escape(text).toString();
    }
```

Comment: what actually you are trying to test ?

Comment: The unit tests should pass... I'm trying to test that my escape method, can escape .'s correctly.

E.g. in english, and without Java mangling it, `.` should result in `\.` `\` should result in `\\` so that \ and the escape character are unambiguous when unescaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never fill the static Maps `ESCAPE_MAP` and `UNESCAPE_MAP`, because you forget the keyword static.

Here's the correct code

```
private final static Map<CharSequence, CharSequence> ESCAPE_MAP = new HashMap<>();
static {
    ESCAPE_MAP.put("\\", "\\\\");
    ESCAPE_MAP.put(".",  "\\.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, god I feel dumb.

Answer (score 0):

I think :

Instead of

```
private final static Map<CharSequence, CharSequence> ESCAPE_MAP = new HashMap<>();{
        ESCAPE_MAP.put("\\", "\\\\");
        ESCAPE_MAP.put(".",  "\\.");
    }
```

You would write :

```
private final static Map<CharSequence, CharSequence> ESCAPE_MAP = new HashMap<CharSequence, CharSequence>() {
        {
            put("\\", "\\\\");
            put(".", "\\.");
        }
    };
```

Comment: Whilst this works, it's widely considered a Java anti pattern. It creates a new sub class for nearly no reason just to have better syntax.